# Converting PHP Variables Into WordPress User Login

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code in my PHP code that is done outside WordPress in another CMS that uses WordPress for the Blog section.

```
$user_info = get_logged_in_user_info($_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']);
define("USERINFO_MEMBERID", $user_info['memberid']);
define("USERINFO_USERNAME", $user_info['username']);
define("USERINFO_EMAIL", $user_info['email']);
define("USERINFO_TRIAL", $user_info['trial']);
```

I would like to use this info to log the user into WordPress when they get to the WordPress page.

Caveat is if this info isn't set, just leave them not logged in.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: getting user information also from wordpress?

Comment: do you have user information in wordpress database?

Comment: 1. Could you please provide more details on how you want to connect the other CMS with WordPress ? It seems that you intend to this on server-side. But there you can't access the user's credentials.
2. Which type of authentication do you have in wordpress and which on in the other CMS ? (Basic, Digest or 3rd party like facebook.)

Comment: The other CMS uses ProxyPass to authenticate the user. So they are now active. I just want to be able to pull the user info which is the code I showed above and apply it to the WordPress install so they are now considered logged in.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `wp_get_current_user()` to get logged in user information.

```
$user_info = wp_get_current_user();
if($user_info->exists()){
define("USERINFO_MEMBERID", $user_info->memberid);
define("USERINFO_USERNAME", $user_info->username);
define("USERINFO_EMAIL", $user_info->email);
define("USERINFO_TRIAL", $user_info->trial);
}
```

Comment: Actually I would just like to force the username from my variable so that when posting it doesn't require the user to input all the required info to post.